# Need to match but exclude from a list

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

`(AEF01?/.*|.*/FC070?/.*).*` will find

```
AEF01/AL020/na/na/na
```

AND

```
ABB03/FC070/na/na/na
```

but not

```
ANB00/FF030/na/na/na
```

But I want it the other way round - I want it to look at the first column and ignore any `AEF01` codes but pick up anything else in that column and also look at the 2nd column and ignore `FC070` but pick up anything else. `AEF01` and `FC070` might not always appear together.

I've tried `[^]` and the `(?!)` and `(?<!)` all to no avail.
I'm desparate to solve this as my project has stalled without this expression.

Comment: Could you clarify it a lil bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use regex pattern

```
((?<=^)(?!AEF01)[A-Z0-9]{5}(?=\/)|(?<=^[A-Z0-9]{5}\/)(?!FC070)[A-Z0-9]{5}(?=\/|$))
```

Comment: What is the difference between `^` and `(?<=^)`?

Comment: @m.buettner - Nothing, just beauty :) This way both parts of `(..|..)` pattern use same logic, as they have lookbehinds and lookaheads.

Comment: I think you are matching the wrong bits though. As I read it, he wants to match all lines, but in the lines with `AEF01` and `FC070` he wants to drop those columns. This would have to be done with capturing groups and/or replacement of course ;).

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way:

```
^(?!AEF01/)\w+/(?!FC070/)\w+/.*$
```

If you needed to exclude the underscore you would need to change `\w` to `[A-Z0-9]`

Tested in Sublime Text 2 which uses the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) regex syntax